# sort divs by the number, no randomize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this great script: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yomoore/RJMhT/119/)

Over here: [Showing random divs using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205166/showing-random-divs-using-jquery)

The problem is that on reload the divs are randomized. I need the divs to show as they are sorted in the html, like 1,2,3,4 etc. And than of course cycle back starting over from div1.

Comment: you mean when reload, show 1, then reload, show 2, then reload, show 3... etc?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. And after the last div comes the first again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version that works between page reloads, using the [cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie):

JavaScript:

```
var divIndex = $.cookie('div_index') || -1;
var divs = $('.Image');
divIndex = (parseInt(divIndex, 10) + 1) % divs.length;
divs.eq(divIndex).show();
$.cookie('div_index', divIndex);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/RJMhT/124/

Comment: Thanks man:-) That is exactle what I was looking for. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I highly recommend looking at my updated solution using localStorage with cookie fallbacks.  LocalStorage is faster than using cookies and preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/):

Updated JavaScript:

```
$("#slideshow").cycle();
```

Markup:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div class="Image"><img src="/image1.jpg">1</div>
    <div class="Image"><img src="/image2.jpg">2</div>
    <div class="Image"><img src="/image3.jpg">3</div>
    <div class="Image"><img src="/image4.jpg">4</div>
    <div class="Image"><img src="/image5.jpg">5</div>
    <div class="Image"><img src="/image6.jpg">6</div>
    <div class="Image"><img src="/image7.jpg">7</div>
</div>
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/RJMhT/120/

Comment: @yomoore - it's very possible I don't understand what you're trying to do (e.g. what "doesn't work"), but the divs are cycled slowly.

Comment: @yomoore - or, do you want to cycle when reloading? That is also ok.

Comment: If you want to reload the page you have to store the index somehow. Refer to wrong2's suggestion.

Comment: @yomoore - First, the posted code isn't very good nor simple at all. A better approach is to pick up a random number and show a single div - sorting isn't necessary here. Next, I can't think of a way of doing this without cookies, as the page resets is *state* when you reload it, and cookies are the way of dealing with that. I suggest you edit your question and explain what sort of a solution you are looking for, these some confusion among  the answerers.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I think I misunderstood your question.  You want a different image to load each time you actually reload the page?  Seems like an odd request.  Let me think about it.

**Answer http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/RJMhT/133/**

**Features:**

- Uses kittens for images. *(My favorite feature).*
- Uses the [jQuery cookie plug-in](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/raw/master/jquery.cookie.js) when localStorage fails.
- Properly cycles through a dynamic amount of images.

---

**Answer: http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/RJMhT/123/**

**Features:**

- Uses kittens for images. *(My favorite feature).*
- Uses the [jQuery cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plug-in.
- When it hits the last one, it goes back to the first.  This is default for cycle.

Comment: Please look at my links for reference. I would really like to use that code with a modification rather than another code with a plugin or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this:

> when reload, show 1, then
>   reload, show 2, then reload, show 3.....

you may have to use some cache technique such as `localStorage` to store the index of the last div, then when reload, read the last index from `localStorage`, calculate the next index, show it.

Comment: I think you'r mistaken me for a pro:)