# I need to randomly show all divs

Tags: jquery

Hi i am new to jquery and iam tryiing for days now , 
I canot make it work for all the divs to radomly change on browser renewal and not only for the 4 divs.
I want in my web site to advertise restaurants and i want every time someone is visiting to show the  restaurants in different order 
i am sure is something sipmle but if you dont know it it seems very difficult !
Any help it will be fantastic , thank you in advanced.

It is for the code  below " showing-random-divs-using-jquery"
wich i found in the this link
[Showing random divs using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205166/showing-random-divs-using-jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".Image").hide();
var elements = $(".Image");
var elementCount = elements.size();
var elementsToShow = 4;
var alreadyChoosen = ",";
var i = 0;
while (i < elementsToShow) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * elementCount);
    if (alreadyChoosen.indexOf("," + rand + ",") < 0) {
        alreadyChoosen += rand + ",";
        elements.eq(rand).show();
        ++i;
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were trying to do?  Obviously the HTML is just the part relevant to the code, you need to include jQuery and such.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".Image").hide();
  var elements = $(".Image");
  var elementCount = elements.size();
  var elementsToShow = 4;
  var alreadyChoosen = ",";
  var i = 0;
  while (i < elementsToShow) {
      var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * elementCount);
      if (alreadyChoosen.indexOf("," + rand + ",") < 0) {
          alreadyChoosen += rand + ",";
          elements.eq(rand).show().appendTo($("#container"));
          ++i;
      }
  }
```

HTML

```
<div id="container"></div>
<div class="Image">1</div>
<div class="Image">2</div>
<div class="Image">3</div>
<div class="Image">4</div>
```