# Show random div javascript, only displays div sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to set up a 404 page so that it will show a random graphic each time a user hits it. Currently the way I have it coded, the graphic is only loaded some of the time(I'd say it's about 50/50 right now). Just looking for a better way to code it so that one of the divs will be shown every time.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="errorpages">
    <div class="error">
        <img src="404.gif">
    </div>

    <div class="error">
        <img src="4042.gif">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
this.random404 = function(){
    var length = $("#errorpages div").length;
    var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*length) + 1;
    $("#errorpages div:nth-child(" + ran + ")").show();
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.error').hide();
    random404();
});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/Pcw9x/). Maybe there is some other problem ?

Comment: You have to keep track of what the user has seen already. Use [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Comment: I don't want to keep track of what the user has seen, I just want it to display a random div each time someone hits that page. If they see the same div 6 times in a row, that's fine, as long as it's random. @Gaurang, It's working there because that's the only code on the page. However, implemented into my site there is a lot of other code so sometimes it's not showing the div(I'm assuming because it's firing before the divs are loaded).

Comment: You're using different selectors for show and hide.  Perhaps this is where your error lies.  Use `$("#errorpages div").hide()` for consistency.

Comment: Thanks Preston, that's a good suggestion, I actually ended up solving in a different way, but I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Why circulate divs? It adds to much additional code. Just set the images to an array and work off of Math.rand from there. Jquery not necessary.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var images = [], index = 0;
images[0] = "Caption 0 <img src='1.gif'>";
images[1] = "Caption 1 <img src='2.gif'>";
images[2] = "Caption 2 <img src='3.gif'>";
images[3] = "Caption 3 <img src='4.gif'>";
images[4] = "Caption 4 <img src='5.gif'>";
images[5] = "Caption 5 <img src='6.gif'>";
images[6] = "Caption 6 <img src='7.gif'>";
images[7] = "Caption 7 <img src='8.gif'>";
index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
document.write("<p>Head</p>" + images[index] + "<p>Foot</p>");
</script>
```

Comment: Because I am also going to be adding in headings and paragraph tags to accompany the images.

Comment: Thanks, but the accompanying text will be different for each image.

Comment: Then append it to the array.....It really doesn't need to be that complicated as jquery. This is a really simplistic concept.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using underscore, you could achieve it using the method _.sample():
http://underscorejs.org/#sample

Or you could use the method _.shuffle() and always pick the first element:
http://underscorejs.org/#shuffle

Comment: Thanks Igor, I actually ended up using a very similar solution to the shuffle method, just not using Underscore. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: No problem! In case you want to improve your shuffle solution, you may enjoy this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going another route. Instead of displaying a random div, I am sorting the divs randomly and then just displaying the first div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var divs = $("div.error").get().sort(function(){ 
            return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
           }).slice(0,1);
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(divs).show();
});
</script>
```

## [SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205166/showing-random-divs-using-jquery)

Comment: I think by doing that you user will end up having to download all images but your javascript will show only one. It's a unnecessary load delivered to your user. A better approach is create a array with all your images, shuffle it and take its first position then take its value and set it to your image's src attribute.