# Use magnific popup to display random div

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I'm using the [magnific popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) plugin to show a modal window containing HTML content in a div.

***When the user triggers the popup, I would like to randomly show one of a number of divs.***

But.. due to my poor javascript skills, I'm unsure how to achieve this with [magnific's API](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api). (To be honest I'm not even sure where to begin!).

Does anybody have any advice on how to use the API achieve what I need?

Many thanks again..

---

**HTML used as the trigger:**

```
<a href="#popup-1" class="open-popup">No</a>
```

**Example of HTML content (one of which to be displayed randomly):**

```
 <div id="popup-1" class="mfp-hide">
   Content here
 </div>

 <div id="popup-2" class="mfp-hide">
   Content here
 </div>

 <div id="popup-3" class="mfp-hide">
   Content here
 </div>
```

**JQuery used to initialise magnific popup:**

```
$('.open-popup').magnificPopup({
    removalDelay: 300,
    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
    closeOnContentClick: true,
    closeBtnInside: true
});
```

**I found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205166/showing-random-divs-using-jquery) that could help with the random div selection? :**

```
 var divs = $("div.Popup").get().sort(function(){ 
  return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5; //random so we get the right +/- combo
 }).slice(0,4)
  $(divs).appendTo(divs[0].parentNode).show();
```